# Can a nested method access parent's values?

Tags: go

I'm trying to create a string view of state, so when called:

```
fmt.Printf("%s", panel.State)
```

It'll will print out something like:

```
Hi
⚪️⚪️⚪️⚪️⚪️⚪️⚪️⚪️⚪️⚪️
⚪️⚫️⚪️⚫️⚪️⚪️⚫️⚪️⚪️⚪️
⚪️⚫️⚪️⚫️⚪️⚪️⚪️⚪️⚪️⚪️
⚪️⚫️⚫️⚫️⚪️⚪️⚫️⚪️⚪️⚪️
⚪️⚫️⚪️⚫️⚪️⚪️⚫️⚪️⚪️⚪️
⚪️⚫️⚪️⚫️⚪️⚪️⚫️⚪️⚪️⚪️
⚪️⚪️⚪️⚪️⚪️⚪️⚪️⚪️⚪️⚪️
```

Is it possible to add a method on a nested field, then have access to it's parent struct, something like:

```
type Panel struct {
  Width  int
  Height int
  Message string

  State [][]bool
}

func (state Panel.State) String() string {
  line := state.parent.Message + "\n"
  for x := 0; x < state.parent.Width; x++ {
    for y := 0; y < state.parent.Height; y++ {
      cell = state[x][y]
      if cell {
        line += "⚫️"
      } else {
        line += "⚪️"
      }
    }
    line += "\n"
  }

  return line
}
```

Comment: No, not possible. You could, however, define a new type (`type State [][]bool`) and define the String method on that.

Comment: If you define a new type, then how would I be able to get access to the parent's `Width` and `Height` fields?

Comment: You can't without an explicit reference.  If that's what you need, define a new method on your Panel type.

Comment: Perhaps you can update your question. Your example shows no usage of the `Width` or `Height` fields. The recommended solution of a `type State [][]bool` meets the conditions of your example

Comment: Updated @Patrick, thanks!